# Shopify Graphql get list of orders

Tags: shopify, graphql

How does one get a list of orders from the shopify Graphql api? I can't even figure out how to get a single order. The nearest I can tell is that my query should look something like this:

```
query{
    node(id:$id){
    __typename
    ... on Order{
      id
        email
    }
  }
}
```

Where `$id` is "An object with an ID to support global identification" according to the docs, but its not clear what that means. For a product, you can retrieve the id like so:

```
shop {
    productByHandle(handle: "red-bicycle") {
      id
    }
  }
```

Which will then return a hash, like this:

`Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0Lzk4OTUyODE0NzU=`

You can then query a product using the node interface like this:

```
node(id: "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0Lzk4OTUyODE0NzU=") {
    id
    ... on Product {
      title
    }
  }
```

But how is this done for an order? For a list of the most recent 5 orders? Why do you have to use the Node interface at all? Why not just query by handle or ID or something instead of using the hash?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query for fetch your users orders list

```
let query = Storefront.buildQuery { $0
            .customer(customerAccessToken: token) { $0
                .orders(first: 20) { $0
                    .edges { $0
                        .node { $0
                            .id()
                            .orderNumber()
                            .totalPrice()
                            .currencyCode()
                            .customerLocale()
                            .customerUrl()
                            .email()
                            .phone()
                            .processedAt()
                            .subtotalPrice()
                            .totalRefunded()
                            .totalShippingPrice()
                            .totalTax()
                            .shippingAddress( { $0
                                .address1()
                                .address2()
                                .city()
                                .company()
                                .country()
                                .countryCode()
                                .firstName()
                                .formatted()
                                .formattedArea()
                                .lastName()
                                .latitude()
                                .longitude()
                                .name()
                                .phone()
                                .province()
                                .provinceCode()
                                .zip()
                            })
                            .lineItems(first: 50) { $0
                                .edges { $0
                                    .cursor()
                                    .node { $0
                                        .quantity()
                                        .title()
                                        .variant{ $0
                                            .id()
                                            .image({ $0
                                                .altText()
                                                .id()
                                                .src()
                                            })
                                            .price()
                                            .sku()
                                        }
                                        .customAttributes{ $0
                                            .key()
                                            .value()
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This query return user's orders list in iOS, Hopefully it will be work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I need ALL orders for a given date range, not just for a single customer. I really need to track sales by collection, but with the REST API you have to get all the orders in your date range, then loop through the line-items in each order, and make a separate GET request for each line-item to get its collections, which quickly hits your API request limit